# Using nested folders with react-rails prerender

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-rails, execjs, server-rendering

I'm trying to set up `react-rails` for my app (https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails).

I had no problem getting it to set up initially, but I'm anticipating a lot of different individual components so I want to organize my `/javascript/components` folder neatly.

So I have something like this

```
components
 character
   avatar-selector
     AvatarSelector.tsx
 HomeLogo.tsx
```

The `AvatarSelector.tsx` exports the component as default.

And I have

```
const componentRequireContext = require.context("components", true);
const ReactRailsUJS = require("react_ujs");
ReactRailsUJS.useContext(componentRequireContext);
```

in both `packs/application.js` and `packs/server-rendering.js`

When I render the `HomeLogo` component everything works fine both with and without prerender. 
When I then go to render the component with `react_component('character/avatar-selector/AvatarSelector', avatar_props, prerender: false)` it also works fine.

But when I switch to `prerender: true` it gives an error.

```
ExecJS::ProgramError: Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.>" when prerendering character/avatar-selector/AvatarSelector
```

I have already tried directly adding

```
const AvatarSelector = require('../components/character/avatar-selector/AvatarSelector')
```

to my packs and trying to render the component as `AvatarSelector` but I still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Regarding Encountered error <ExecJS::ProgramError: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: ...:
```

I think one of the core issues is that module lookup uses try...catch. While the errors are logged to the console shim, that typically doesn't help as a later error (such as the invariant violation) will lead to a fatal error (triggering a 500). If that could be refactored to be a bit more intentional based on environment (instead of just reacting based on exceptions, or at the very least, throwing if the caught exception isn't very specific)

```
EDIT: Here's something you can do to help with the Invariant Violation bug:

In app/javascripts/packs/server_rendering.js, replace ReactRailsUJS.useContext('require.context('components', true)); with

// So that we don't fall back to the global namespace (which leads to hard to
// parse errors).
function fromRequireContext(reqctx) {
  return function(className) {
    const parts = className.split('.');
    const filename = parts.shift();
    const keys = parts;
    // Load the module:
    let component = reqctx('./' + filename);
    // Then access each key:
    keys.forEach((k) => {
      component = component[k];
    });
    // support `export default`
    if (component.__esModule) {
      component = component.default;
    }
    return component;
  };
}
ReactRailsUJS.getConstructor = fromRequireContext(require.context('components', true));
```

Reference - https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails/issues/264